# How to Change the cursor in JavaFX Accordion title bar

Tags: javafx-8

I'm using custom cursors and it need to be differ in some components in my screen.

When I set the cursor for **Accordion**, it doesn't effects title headers but effects the body of each **TitledPanes**. I even tried to set the cursor for each TitledPane but it doesn't effect the title header. I'm using following way to change the cursor.

```
ImageCursor cursor_title = new ImageCursor(cursorImg_title,cursorImg_title.getWidth() / 2,cursorImg_title.getHeight() / 2);
accordionBody.setCursor(cursor_title);
```

Is there a way to change the cursor in title bar of a JavaFX Accordian?

More....

I have changed the padding of title bars using css as follows. Hope it doesn't have any relation to the problem.

```
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-padding: 30;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TitledPane is divided into two parts :

- Title
- Content

When you are setting the Cursor on the Accordion, it delegates it to the content of each TitledPane, but leaves the Title. This is by design.

To force your application to change the cursor on the title as well, we need to set it on each of these nodes. We can fetch all the nodes by using the `lookupAll()` on the accordion and passing the styleclass they use i.e. `.title`. *Make sure you use this after the scene graph is visible.*

```
accordion.lookupAll(".title").forEach(node -> node.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND));
```

You can use your custom cursor in place of `CLOSED_HAND`.

Comment: You can set the cursor directly in a css file too, which might be easier than messing with lookups: `.accordian .title { -fx-cursor: ... }`

Comment: @James_D `.accordian` ?? Don't see anything happened. You mean `.titled-pane >` isn't it? But when I used `.titled-pane > .title { -fx-cursor: url("myCursor.gif") }` it gives me a error as `java.lang.String cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Cursor`